# python loop to run only once for temporary testing

Tags: python

I have a python for loop that iterates over a dictionary. 
The dictionary is very large. For debugging I want to modify the for loop to run only once. How can I limit the for loop to exit after running once.

```
for key in dic:
  do_some_stuff()
  #after the first iteration exit
```

In java I can modify the for loop in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  doSomeStuff();
```

will be limited like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n, i < 1; i++)
  doSomeStuff();
```

Comment: You're not using `key`, why not simply call `do_some_stuff` once?

Comment: @MarounMaroun It is most likely an example, not the actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break):

> It terminates the nearest enclosing loop, skipping the optional else
>   clause if the loop has one.

```
for key in dic:
    do_some_stuff()
    break
```

If you want to run the loop for several times (more than once), you can use a counter:

```
for i, key in enumerate(dic):
    do_some_stuff()
    if i > 10:
        break
```

This will run the loop for 11 times before `break`ing as index (i) begins from 0 and goes till 10 .

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing debugging, I would like to recommend you the pdb package:
With it, you got much more control over the execution process.

```
   import pdb
   pdb.set_trace()
   for key in dic:
        do_some_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always slice the dictionary iterator using

```
from itertools import islice

for k in islice(dic, 1):
    do_something(k)
```

Then, to disable it, simply change the `1` to `None`.  Thus you could have a debug flag that decides for you:

```
please_debug = True
for k in islice(dic, 1 if please_debug else None):
    do_something(k)
```